Is it possible to disable “Coalesced Acknowledge Messages” for RDMA Write?
According to the IB specification, "Coalesced Acknowledge Messages" means "It is not required that there be a unique, discrete response for each request packet. Instead, the responder may acknowledge several outstanding request packets with a single acknowledge packet."
Coalesced Acknowledge Messages
And in my own tests, I've comfirmed that the number of RDMA write request packets exceeds the number of acknowledge packets, indicating that the requests and acknowledgements are not strictly one-to-one.
For my specific needs, I would like each RDMA write request to trigger a unique acknowledge from the responding NIC, rather than using a single acknowledge to respond to multiple requests. Is there a way to achieve this?
Previously, I used a script with mstmcra to disable ICRC checking, and I wonder if there might be a similar method to disable "Coalesced Acknowledge Messages" for RDMA write? I'm using ConnectX-5.
Thank you in advance for any insights or advice you can offer!

“Unfortunately, the addressed behavior will need to validated behavior with Engineering Team and requires debug.“ - referenced from NVIDIA Community.
